# Flex-Sorting on ArrayCollection

Tags: apache-flex

I have an ArrayCollection(neList) of Objects(neObj). Each neObj has several fields like ipAddress,TID,etc.. In most cases neObj will be have values of both TID and ipAddress, rarely it will not have TID but have ipAddress... After adding Objects(neObj), I need to sort the ArrayCollection whose behaviour must be similar to array.sort() which has got strings only..(i.e nos first followed by strings in alphabetical order)

Things I have tried:
1)Using neList.source.sort() and neList.refresh.. but it did not work as neList.source has objects not straight forward things like strings
2)I think i cannot use sortOn function of ArrayCollection as it can be done on only 1 field

My Requirement:
Use Case1:- Objects in ArrayCollection have both TID and IP
neObj1.TID="RAPC" neObj1.ipAddress="121.1.1.2"; neObj2.TID="RAPA" neObj2.ipAddress="121.1.1.1"
O/P after sorting should be
neObj2 neObj1

Use Case2:- 1 of the objects does not have TID
neObj1.ipAddress="121.1.1.2"; neObj2.TID="RAPA" neObj2.ipAddress="121.1.1.1"
O/P after sorting should be
neObj1 neObj2

Comment: These are the docs on using Sort with ArrayCollection: http://flex.apache.org/asdoc/spark/collections/Sort.html

Comment: You need a sortCompareFunction; if you Google around I'm sure you'll find a bunch of samples and more detailed docs.

Comment: Thanks.. I will try with sortCompareFunction.. But am not sure why this is not working...:(

Comment: `var sumObj1:Object = new Object();
    sumObj1.TID="A";
    sumObj1.ipAddress=3;    
    sumObj2.TID="F";
    sumObj2.ipAddress=2;    
    sumObj3.TID="C";
    sumObj3.ipAddress=1;    
    neList.addItem(sumObj2);
    neList.addItem(sumObj1);    
   neList.addItem(sumObj3);
bla bla   
   var newSort:Sort = new Sort();
   newSort.fields = [new SortField("TID")];    
   neList.sort = newSort;
   neList.refresh();    
   ObjectUtil.toString(obj);`

The arrayCollection is not getting sorted as A C F.. Am not sure where I went wrong :( :(

Answer (score 0):

As hinted in the comments, you'll need to use a sort compareFunction to decide how the items will be sorted.

I do like to point out that sorting a combination of letters and numbers is tricky in the sense that there is no natural order by default. e.g. when sorting, 1, 2 and 11, the order will be 1, 11, 2. You can however solve this using the [naturalCompare](http://www.as3commons.org/as3-commons-lang/asdoc/org/as3commons/lang/StringUtils.html#naturalCompare%28%29) method in the [AS3Commons Lang](http://www.as3commons.org/as3-commons-lang/index.html) project.

Here's a code sample for your case. The sort is implemented as a subclass of the Sort class so that you can easily reuse it in other collections:

```
package {

import mx.collections.Sort;

import org.as3commons.lang.StringUtils;

public class NaturalSort extends Sort {

  public function NaturalSort() {
    compareFunction = function (a:Object, b:Object, fields:Array = null):int {
      var stringA:String = (("TID" in a) ? a.TID : "AAAA") + a.ipAddress;
      var stringB:String = (("TID" in b) ? b.TID : "AAAA") + b.ipAddress;
      return StringUtils.naturalCompare(stringA, stringB);
    };
  }
}
}
```

To apply this:

```
var collection:ArrayCollection;
collection.sort = new NaturalSort();
collection.refresh();
```